# Remove html injection?

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

```
<textarea id="insTxt"></textarea>
<h1 id="getTxt">...</h1>
<button id="getBtn" onclick="getText()">Click Me</button>
```

JS:

```
function getText() {
    document.getElementById('getTxt').innerHTML = document.getElementById('insTxt').value;
}
```

In the code above, I can enter HTML codes in the textarea and they will be used in the actual code. For example, if I typed `<button>BLAHBLAH</button>` in the textarea and clicked the "Click Me" button, it would add that "BLAHBLAH" button. 
How would this be prevented?

Comment: `innerHTML` parses the string as HTML, `textContent` (which you probably want instead) does not.

Comment: This is called XSS (cross site scripting). Have a look at this link for the solution. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A3-Cross-Site_Scripting_(XSS)

Comment: Always remember that all of this happens on the **client**. The client can easily change JS and HTML at will in any case. If you  plan to send that data to the server, however, that is where the data should be properly sanitized.

Comment: @KiranVarsani I fail to see how this is cross site...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the innerText property.

```
function getText() {
    document.getElementById('getTxt').innerText = document.getElementById('insTxt').value;
}
```

Comment: inner text does not work with firefox. 

     if (doucment.all) { document.getElementById('getTxt').innerText .... }      else { document.getElementById("insTxt").textContent ....}

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Comment: Crickey! It's been so long since I worked with the raw JavaScript DOM, I had no idea! Hooray for...web standards?